# How to check if the element exist in Cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp

What is the best way to check if the an element, a .ctp file exist in cakephp 3 ?

Something like this,

```
<?php
// if the elemet exist display it
$this->render('/Element/Trip/'.$current_step);
// else display another element instead
?>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and use [the Controller::$viewPath property](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-Controller.html#123-128).

But this is IMHO bad practice because you should know your elements and not rely on guessing. `$current_step` implies there are some steps, guess they're finite. So instead of doing the check in the view check if the step is in your range of steps from 1 to 5 in the controller for example and if it's not throw a NotFoundException. The exception will return a 404, so you can check your response for that status code when handling the response in your client via JS.

```
public function my_action($step) {
    if (!in_array($step, ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'done']) {
        throw new \NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i guess you're right. I've to input hidden in my form which is current_step and next_step, by Ajax is there is no validation error i set the next step so that's why i was asking in case if there is someone who change the values. How can i do ? If i name 1, 2 or 3 the name of my elements how can i do in php ?

Comment: Check if the param or form field (whatever you use)? Just use in_array() to check if that value is in the list of allowed steps? See my updated answer as well for checking if the step doesn't' exist.

Comment: You might want to cache the result because file system accesses are resource intensive.

Answer (score 6):

Use `$this->elementExists`:

```
<?php
 if ($this->elementExists('Trip/'.$current_step)) {
   echo $this->element('Trip/'.$current_step);
 } else {
   echo $this->element('Trip/default.ctp');  
 }
```

http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.View.html#_elementExists

if you don't want display another element but don't throw exception, you can use `ignoreMissing` option

```
$this->element('Trip/'.$current_step,$data, ['ignoreMissing' => true])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// if the elemet exist display it
if(file_exists ('/Element/Trip/'.$current_step))
$this->render('/Element/Trip/'.$current_step);
else
// else display another element instead
?>
```

Comment: This won't work without the current $viewPath. See http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-Controller.html#123-128

Answer (score 0):

You have to check file is existed or not?. If file is existed then do some thing or else do some thing

```
<?php
// if element exists
$element='/Element/Trip/'.$current_step;
if(file_exists($element))
   $this->render($element);
else
{
   // Display another element.
}
?>
```

Comment: Same problem as the other answer: This won't work without the current $viewPath. See http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-Controller.html#123-128